# Connecting to IoT Core MQTT

Tags: arduino, google-cloud-platform, mqtt, esp32, google-cloud-iot

I am trying to connect to Google's MQTT server but I am getting errors
I created all the certificates and registered my device (Adafruit huzzah32)

and the documentation says you connect to `mqtt.googleapis.com:8883`

So I do

```cpp
WiFiClientSecure wifi;
MQTTClient client;
client.begin("mqtt.googleapis.com", 8883, wifi);
```

When I try to connect I use the device path

```cpp
const char* jwt = "{json web token}";
const char* device = "projects/{project-id}/locations/{cloud-region}/registries/{registry-id}/devices/{device-id}";

Serial.print("Connecting to mqtt");
while (!client.connect(device,"unused",jwt)) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(1000);
}

Serial.println();
Serial.println("Connected to mqtt");
```

but it never connects

I verified the google certificate by calling 
`openssl s_client -showcerts -connect mqtt.googleapis.com:8883`
and I put in my RSA Private key and certificate key that was made

```
wifi.setCACert(googleCertificate2);
wifi.setCertificate(myCertificate);
wifi.setPrivateKey(privateCert);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the connection documentation
https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/mqtt-bridge

**Update**

I made a quick java example to see if I can connect going off the example they have for connecting and I get a `MqttException` saying `Bad user name or password (4)`

Here is the code for that

```
private void doStuff(){
        String clientId = String.format("ssl://%s:%s", "mqtt.googleapis.com", 8883);
        String mqttClientId = String.format("projects/%s/locations/%s/registries/%s/devices/%s","{project_id}", "us-central1", "{register}", "{device}");
        MqttConnectOptions connectOptions = new MqttConnectOptions();
        connectOptions.setMqttVersion(MqttConnectOptions.MQTT_VERSION_3_1_1);

        Properties sslProps = new Properties();
        sslProps.setProperty("com.ibm.ssl.protocol", "TLSv1.2");
        connectOptions.setSSLProperties(sslProps);

        connectOptions.setUserName("unused");


        try{
            String jwt = createJwtRsa("{project-id}");
            connectOptions.setPassword(jwt.toCharArray());
            MqttClient client = new MqttClient(clientId, mqttClientId, new MemoryPersistence());

            while(!client.isConnected()){
                try{
                    client.connect(connectOptions);
                }catch (MqttException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            Log.d("","");
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private String createJwtRsa(String projectId) throws Exception {
        DateTime now = new DateTime();
        JwtBuilder jwtBuilder =
                Jwts.builder().setIssuedAt(now.toDate()).setExpiration(now.plusDays(1000000).toDate()).setAudience(projectId);

        byte[] keyBytes = readBytes(getAssets().open("rsa_private_pkcs8"));
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

        PrivateKey k = kf.generatePrivate(spec);

        return jwtBuilder.signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.RS256, k).compact();
    }
```

As you can see here I have the IoT service acount added to IAM
[image]

Does that mean my keys that I generated with openssl are incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem ended up being that I was trying to set a really large expiration date on my Json Web Token (on purpose so I didnt have to keep generating new ones since I have not found a way to do that in arduino) and it looks like that google's mqtt server does not accept anything over a day so the keys will have to be updated daily.

Also inorder to connect to the MQTT server I had to change the buffer size of the MqttClient on the arduino to have a buffer size of 1024 bytes.

```
MQTTClient client(1024);
```

anything less I would get an error saying buffer isnt big enough.

Comment: found another client for Arduino https://pubsubclient.knolleary.net/index.html - that "buffer" might be either the `MQTT_MAX_PACKET_SIZE` or the `MQTT_MAX_TRANSFER_SIZE`.

Comment: Hello! I'm also trying to connect my Arduino board with Google IoT Core but I don't how to generate the JWT token. How was your approach to generate the token?

Comment: @Marlon I created an AppEngine endpoint that I call on arduino to get a token and just used the java example they have for the IoT documentation. Though if your board does not support SSL/TLS this wont work

Comment: Another solution I was working with is I use a Raspberry Pi3 running Android Things to create the key and send it to the board over bluetooth

Comment: Thanks @tyczj! I've been thinking about a solution like yours but in my case, I thought that maybe I could have a gateway that is responsible for redirecting all messages from devices to IoT Core. This gateway, in this case, will be responsible for generating the JWT token for each device and send the message to Google. The drawback of this solution is that I'll need to store the private keys in this gateway and map each device to its private key.

Answer (score 0):

here the [IAM](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/iam) roles are being explained ...the paragraph [here](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/troubleshooting) sounds alike what you describe:

> On the IAM page in Google Cloud Platform Console, verify that the role Cloud IoT Core Service Agent appears in the Members list for the relevant project service account. (Look for the project service account that ends in @gcp-sa-cloudiot.iam.gserviceaccount.com.)
>
> If the Cloud IoT Core Service Agent role does not appear in the Members list, use gcloud to add the cloudiot.serviceAgent role to the relevant project service account. This role includes permission to publish to Pub/Sub topics.

if not yet having installed it, the [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads) is required for all those `gcloud` CLI commands, which can be used to list & edit the configurations (of which all can be done through the console, as well)... it's maybe easier, because all of the examples there use it, too.

**update** ...

concerning JWT refresh tokens, see this [article](https://auth0.com/blog/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/) or have some [Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=MQTT%20JWT) or the specification: [JSON Web Token (JWT)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519), [JSON Web Token (JWT) Profile for OAuth 2.0 Client Authentication and Authorization Grants](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-jwt-bearer-12).
here's another relevant article: https://medium.com/google-cloud/refreshing-json-web-tokens-jwts-for-google-cloud-iot-core-897318df3836

Comment: all those things check out (IAM service agent and gcloud commands find devices)

Comment: Ok so just an update now, The problem with the java example I think was that I needed to update the gradle dependencies to the latest version, I did that and I was able to connect so what am I missing in the c++ arduino code then?